# Swift Inheritance(Extending classes)

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

i have two classes ClassA,ClassB,ClassC and ClassC is extended from ClassA

```
open class classA: NSObject{
    var firstName = String()
    var lastName = String()
}
open class classB: NSObject{
    public func getObject(dictionary : Dictionary<String,Any>) -> Dictionary<String,Any>{
       var Dict : [String: Any] = [:]
       var ListArray = Array<Any>()
       let tempArray = dictionary["data"] as! Array<Any>
    
    for item in 0..<tempArray.count{
        let dict = tempArray[item] as! NSMutableDictionary
        let myclass = classA()
       
        if let val = dict["firstName"] as? String{
            myclass.firstName = val
        }else if let val =  dict["lastName"] as? String{
            myclass.lastName = val
        }
        ListArray.append(myclass)
    }
    Dict["data"] = ListArray
    
    return Dict
}
```

}

if i extend the ClassC like this

```
public ClassC : ClassA{
   var age = String()
   var address = String()

}
```

Is there any way to use this ClassC variables in class B function getObjects ?
i can't move ClassC variables to ClassA.
Can any one help me to achieve this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why can't B extends from A? Otherwise this looks to be fast becoming a factory class which might be used by C (and others) independently

Comment: @MadProgrammer thanks for your comment can you please explain a little bit, am new to programming.

Comment: If you want C to have the functionality of both A and B, then B must inherit from A, then C will get inherit the functionality of both A and B.  On the other hand, if you want B to be more generic and used in more use cases, then B would become a "factory" class, which C would create an instance of internally and make use of

Answer (score 0):

You can use the type as value and pass it as a parameter:

```swift
class ClassB {
    func someFunc(A: ClassA.Type) {
        let classA = A.init(f: "firstName", l: "lastName")
        print(classA)
    }
}
```

You'll have to pass the type like this:

```swift
let b = ClassB()
b.someFunc(A: ClassA.self)
```

Swift's polymorphism applies here which means even if you pass `ClassC`, it'll be permitted:

```swift
let b = ClassB()
b.someFunc(A: ClassC.self)
```

You'll have to have a required initializer for the subclasses:

```swift
open class ClassA: NSObject{
    var firstName: String?
    var lastName: String?
    required public init(f: String = "", l: String = "") {
        self.firstName = f
        self.lastName = l
    }
}

class ClassC : ClassA {
    var age = String()
    var address = String()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay its working fine but, this classA is general example i took in real time my class has more then 70 variable declaration. is this necessary to public init method? is there any way to init all variables at one time

Comment: Sure, initializers are like regular functions. You include more parameters in it to initialize more variables. You can't, however, initialize the properties of the subclass.